# Data.Foldable for unordered containers

Tags: haskell, typeclass, parametric-polymorphism

I'm working on a Haskell-meets-SQL language for database manipulations, and on a common type class library to go with it, cribbing from Hackage wherever it makes sense.

Because a significant objective of a database query optimizer is to eliminate unnecessary sorting, it's important to preserve a static representation of where sorting is in fact necessary. Which brings us to defining a typeclass for folds.

Haskell's `Data.Foldable` has: (eliding default definitions which aren't relevant to the point I'm making)

```
class Foldable t where
  -- | Combine the elements of a structure using a monoid.
  fold :: Monoid m => t m -> m

  -- | Map each element of the structure to a monoid,
  -- and combine the results.
  foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m

  -- | Right-associative fold of a structure.
  foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b

  -- | Left-associative fold of a structure.
  foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> t b -> a

  -- | A variant of 'foldr' that has no base case,
  -- and thus may only be applied to non-empty structures.
  foldr1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a

  -- | A variant of 'foldl' that has no base case,
  -- and thus may only be applied to non-empty structures.
  foldl1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a
```

It seems to me that this class ignores a distinction which is, for practical purposes, not so important to most Haskell applications but of much more interest in a database setting. To wit: all `Data.Foldable` instances come with an ordering.

**What is the name for the generalization of this concept that applies at container types which don't impose an ordering on their elements?**

For Haskell `Data.Set`s it works out fine, because there is an `Ord` context required by the implementation. The ordering requirement is an implementation artifact though, and for many useful types the ordering being used may not have any domain-level meaning.

For sets more generally the `fold :: Monoid m => t m -> m` definition on its own is mostly right (so is `foldMap`). I say mostly because its type includes the associativity law (through the definition of `Monoid`) but not the required commutativity law. The other variants don't even exist.

I don't want to introduce sorts where they aren't needed. I also don't want to introduce **non-determinism** where it can't be tracked. I'm interested in building a language and library that doesn't have a `toList :: Set a -> [a]` function lying around anywhere, because it introduces a dichotomy between:

1. Allowing people to observe implementation details about how a set/relation is physically stored
2. Losing track of non-determinism as an effect

Obviously both `sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> Set a -> [a]` and `shuffle :: Set a -> Data.Random.RVar [a]` are useful, unobjectionable, and will be included. In fact, `sortBy` has an even more general type as `sortBy :: (TheUnorderedFoldableClassIAmTryingToName f) => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> f a -> [a]`.

**What is this idea called? If I'm way off base, where did I leave the base path?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation performed by your fold-like operator would not operate over a monoid, but rather, a commutative semigroup. That gives you `op :: (CSemi a) => f a -> a  -> a`

In the literature I've seen, the typical name for your operator/typeclass would just be CFold -- short for commutative fold. (YAHT also uses cfold as the name for a cps-style fold, but I don't think that's in common usage)